# Can you recommend: a mailing list script?

Tags: php, scripting

I'm looking for a subscribe/unsubscribe mailing list to install on my website.

**Requirements:**

- PHP/MySQL;
- Cron job: *uses scheduling to send email in batches*;
- Multiple languages: *when user is subscribing, they need to select preferred language from a drop-down*;
- Send in both HTML/Text;
- Bounce-email check;
- Double opt-in: *user must confirm email before being subscribed*.
- Unsubscribe link: *being able to unsubscribe by following a link in the email*.

Any suggestions? Could be paid license as well (maximum $40). However, I'm not interested in hosted services with monthly fees.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a go with List Messenger? http://www.listmessenger.com/ It's not great, but it is pretty well featured and it's all in PHP so you can hack it about if you want to.

Comment: I tried the demo and it looks really nice. However, a little more than I want to be paying for each license.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of PHP mailing list applications around, and to my surprise, almost all turned out to be total crap. At least the open source ones.

The only free one that I have used myself and was happy with is [PoMMO](http://pommo.org/Main_Page). I don't think it can do cron-powered batch sending, and I'm not sure about automated bounce handling, but the rest should be achievable: You can create custom signup forms so language selection shouldn't be a problem (and later, putting subscribers into groups according to the selection).

It seems to have been inactive  since 2008, and the back-end template needs a bit of reworking to look good in Firefox, but it has been a reliable workhorse.

Anyway. The PHPList project @Gordon suggests looks more active, which is always good in a public-facing software. Maybe try that first.

Answer (score 0):

http://phplist.com/ comes to mind

Comment: It can have been me, but I tried this once and turned away in horror. A usability nightmare. However, that was almost two years ago so things can have improved.

Comment: @Pekka I've installed it for a client once a couple years ago. They never used it so I really cant tell much about it. I'm just suggesting it because it covers the OP's requested features. In the end, the OP has to see for himself if it suits the need.

Comment: yup. As I said, it can have been me starting on the wrong foot somehow, seeing as it's the most popular mailing list application and *must* be some good. Also, it's under active development which is good.

Comment: I tried phplist last night. I'll have to agree, nightmare. The interface was really confusing. If I can't use it, and I'm the developer, then my client certainly won't have time to figure it out either.